# Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Pick<IJobs, "name">'

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

Why I get this error?

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Pick<IJobs, "name">'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Pick<IJobs, "name">'
```

mockData:

```
export const Jobs: IJobs[] = [
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'Trader',
    available: true
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'Seller',
    available: true
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    name: 'Manager',
    available: false
  },
  {
    id: '4',
    name: 'Cleaner',
    available: false
  }
];
```

Model:

```
export interface IJobs {
  id: string;
  name: 'Trader' | 'Seller' | 'Manager' | 'Cleaner';
  available: boolean;
}
```

Main.tsx

```
  const handleSetJobsAndOpenModal = (jobs: Pick<IJobs, 'name'>) => {
    setCurrentJobs(jobs);
  };
  const scrollData = useCallback(() => (
    <View style={s.containerMap}>
     {
       Jobs.map(((el) => (
         <Pressable onPress={() => handleSetJobsAndOpenModal(el.name)} style={s.Btn} key={el.id}>
           <Text>...</Text>
         </Pressable>
       )))
     }
     </View>
  ), [])
```

The error comes at " () => handleSetJobsAndOpenModal(el.name) <-"

What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are picking `name` from `IJobs`. This will yield in a `key-value pair`.

Thus, it is expected by the type `Pick<IJobs, 'name'>` that it receives an object with a key named `name` and a value being one of `'Trader' | 'Seller' | 'Manager' | 'Cleaner'`.

The error can be solved as follows.

```
handleSetJobsAndOpenModal({name: el.name})
```

If you just want the plain string, then I would suggest that you separate the types as follows.

```js
export type JobName = 'Trader' | 'Seller' | 'Manager' | 'Cleaner'

export interface IJobs {
  id: string;
  name: JobName;
  available: boolean;
}
```

Then, use it as follows.

```
const handleSetJobsAndOpenModal = (jobs: JobName) => {
    setCurrentJobs(jobs);
  };
  const scrollData = useCallback(() => (
    <View style={s.containerMap}>
     {
       Jobs.map(((el) => (
         <Pressable onPress={() => handleSetJobsAndOpenModal(el.name)} style={s.Btn} key={el.id}>
           <Text>...</Text>
         </Pressable>
       )))
     }
     </View>
  ), [])
```